# pass a function parameter value NULL in c

Tags: c, function

I need to create a function that will split array into 2. Here's the parameters
int splitarr(int *array,int ogsize, int size1,int *arr1, int *arr2)
The task that i have the arrays must not be created before the function call -> the arr1 and arr2 value has to be NULL and i have to create the arrays inside the function.

Comment: what is `size1`?

Comment: size1 is the size point of splitting array if size1 =3 then first array has 3 elemts the 2nd one has the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want instead of passing in null, is to pass in a pointer to a pointer. Your function signature should look like this:

```
int splitarr(int *array, int ogsize, int size1, int **arr1, int **arr2);
```

Note the double star. Your function then does something like this:

```
int splitarr(int *array, int ogsize, int size1, int **arr1, int **arr2) {
    int* a1 = malloc(size1 * sizeof(int));
    int* a2 = malloc((ogsize - size1) * sizeof(int));
    // perform some copying operations here
    *arr1 = a1;
    *arr2 = a2;
}
```

Now when you call it:

```
int *resultOfSplit1;
int *resultOfSplit2;
splitarr(originalArr, originalSize, size1, &resultOfSplit1, &resultOfSplit2);
```

This will store the new allocated arrays in those 2 variables.